# CakePHP Multiple belongsto a model

Tags: model, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many, belongs-to, contain

I have tried a lot of scenarios but it fails.

I need to map 3 accounts using belongs to model.

```
$conditions['OR']['ClientActuarialForm.abn'] = $keyword;
$conditions['OR']['ClientActuarialForm.certificate_display_id'] = $keyword;
$conditions['OR']['ClientActuarialForm.id'] = $memberMatches;
$conditions['OR']['ClientActuarialForm.fund_name LIKE'] = '%' . $keyword . '%';

$this->ClientActuarialForm->belongsTo['ClientClassRequest'] = [
    "foreignKey" => false,
    "conditions" => array("ClientClassRequest.smsf_actuarial_form_id = ClientActuarialForm.id"),
];
$this->ClientActuarialForm->belongsTo['GroupAccount'] = [
    "foreignKey" => false,
    "conditions" => array("GroupAccount.id = ClientActuarialForm.created_group_account_id"),
];
```

In these now, I need to add a condition

```
$conditions['OR']['Account.email LIKE'] = '%' . $this->Account->encrypt($keyword) . '%';
```

Need to map 2 table to **ClientActuarialForm**. The following table are

1. GroupAccountToApprovedCustomerUser
2. Account

Database

1. Account - [Accounts Table Structure with sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKNiq.png)
2. GroupAccountToApprovedCustomerUser -

[image]

3. ClientActuarialForm - given in comment box

   - Now I come to point if keyword is email id, then I need to search email id in account Id table.`account.email = keyword`
   - By using account id search group account id from 2nd table(GroupAccountToApprovedCustomerUser) (i.e) `GroupAccountToApprovedCustomerUser.customer_id = Account.id`
   - By using group account id find form data in ClientActuarialForm `ClientActuarialForm.created_group_account_id = GroupAccountToApprovedCustomerUser.group_account_id`

Comment: ClientActuarialForm - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux3sb.png

Comment: All relationships should be done in your Model for each Class.